# Associate images to array element result

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, dom, render

I'm exercising my skills with a simple card game. I've managed to draw a card randomizing and looping through arrays. My question is. How could I now associate each card to an image for it to be rendered into the Dom without having to make 53 else if statements? Is there an easier way?
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

add("card");
                cardRender.innerHTML = topCard;


                
                
                //If else argument to tell the computer when the deck is finished!
                if(topCard === undefined){
                    document.getElementById("carpetId").innerHTML = "The deck is EMPTY! Reshuffle it.";
                }else{
                    
                    document.getElementById("carpetId").appendChild(cardRender);
                }
                
                
                const delFirstEl = cardDeck.shift();
            
                        return false;
            }
            

        </script>
        

        <script>
            /*$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btnTest").click(function(){
                    $("#cardDrawerBox").animate({left: '200px'});
                });
            });*/


            

            $("#cardDeckId").click(function(){
            $('#cardDrawerBox').animate({
                
                top: '300px',
            }, 500, function() {
            $('#cardDrawerBox').removeAttr('style');
            });
});
        </script>
        

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ignore this question

Comment: There was a problem while posting, I'll try again

Answer (score 0):

If you name your images like your cards, you can simply get the file using the name of the card in the path: `public/cards/${cardID}.jpeg` or something like this